# Dot Net Nuke "A critical error has occurred. An unexpected error has occurred"

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

Helping a friend with an old install of Dot Net Nuke (I don't know what version but it looks old, before it was just DNN). The homepage for some reason has stopped loading content. The nav and content do *not* load but the structure and styles do. All other pages seem fine.

Message on homepage says "A critical error has occurred. An unexpected error has occurred". I don't know anything about DNN, help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Dot Net Nuke will show this message when an exception has been thrown.
from the menu under Admin select Event Viewer. there is a list of all exception there. from that list you can find out what's causing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Is this website was running earlier, is setup done properly?

**2.** If it is not, please create a empty database on local SQL server & then update the connection string from web.config. Create a virtual directory/application on local IIS and point this website there. Then check for install.aspx / setup.aspx and brown it thru IIS. 
While setup is running, it will ask for host user ID & password provide accordingly.

Possible then check readme.txt file in folder which may provide current version.

If error still shows up, I request to upload screenshot.